# Trouble getting RPi device data in IBM IoT input node

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, iot, node-red, watson-iot

I'm having trouble getting "device" data from a Raspberry Pi to show up via an IBM IoT input node in Node-RED.  I know the data is making it into the Watson IoT cloud, since I can see it under "recent events" in the device panel.  However, I'm getting an "Imported Unrecognized Type: wiotp-credentials" error when I refresh Node-RED.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Since you said you had solved this on Slack, any chance you can come add an answer on here so others can benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, amadain was correct.  I had two browsers open with NodeRed, one for bluemix and the other for a Pi ... and inadvertently cut & pasted some node information from the Pi to blumix.  Once I removed the errant node, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting you imported something from a NodeRed flow on the Pi to NodeRed on bluemix?  There are slight differences in the nodes and also credentials don't import.  You might want to add a new IBMIOT (Input) node and then create new credentials.  Take or create the API keys from your organisation-access-api keys (https://.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/dashboard/#/access/apikeys